# Android Gradle Error

Tags: android, gradle

i am trying to build a sample android project with gradle. but i keep getting this error

```
Error:(11, 0) Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'SliMe'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
```

this is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
}
 assert gradle.gradleVersion >= "1.10"
 apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
   }
```

i downloaded and installed gradle 1.11 locally. i am using android studio

Comment: Sounds like you might also be using some other plugin (full stack trace would help). Version strings can't be compared lexicographically - the assertion will pass for every version greater than 1.1.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit further. i which part of the code should i provide.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by downgrading to gradle 1.10, it worked fine.